# Cbind not working as expected Time series object R

Tags: r

Original dataset

```
test_data1
         Date Quantity Discount Segment Ship_Mode
1  2018-02-01      345     5000      20        20
2  2018-03-01      500      300      50        20
3  2018-04-01      400      400      40        30
4  2018-05-01      200      400     100        20
```

Now I created dummies for seasonality named dummy_test

```
   dummy_test<- seasonaldummy(test_data1)
       Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov
 [1,]   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [2,]   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [3,]   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [4,]   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I am trying to join the 2 dataframes so that I have a combined dataframe which has both seasonality dummies and the other columns. (want to combine 2 to 4 th columns of test_data1

```
cbind(dummy_test,test_data1[,c(2:4)])
Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = FALSE, union = TRUE) : 
  non-time series not of the correct length
```

Structure

```
sapply(test_data1,class)
 Quantity  Discount   Segment Ship_Mode 
     "ts"      "ts"      "ts"      "ts"
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide us with `dummy_test` and `test_data1` (to preserve the data types).

Comment: ` dput(test_data1)
structure(c(345L, 500L, 400L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 
400L, 500L, 5000L, 300L, 400L, 400L, 200L, 200L, 300L, 300L, 
400L, 500L, 500L, 20L, 50L, 40L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 50L, 100L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 
50L, 60L), .Dim = c(11L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Quantity", 
"Discount", "Segment", "Ship_Mode")), .Tsp = c(2018.08333333333, 
2018.91666666667, 12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))`

Comment: pls check above for dputs....

Comment: As the error message says, the problem is, that your datasets have different column lengths (12 vs. 44). What is you expected result?

Comment: also test_data1 is a mts object - try coercing it to a matrix/dataframe for the cbind then converting it back to an mts (by using as.data.frame() or as.matrix())

Comment: Sorry, 11 not 12, please see: `cbind(dummy_test[1:11,], test_data1[, c(2:4)])`

Comment: This works for me: `cbind(as.data.frame(test_data1), as.data.frame(dummy_test))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function does the job

```
cbind(as.data.frame(test_data1), as.data.frame(dummy_test))
```